# Homework: A parachutist jumps from a plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I need help with the following problem. I think I almost have it . . .

A parachutist bails out and freely falls a distance of $y_1$. Then the parachute opens and thereafter, the parachutist decelerates at a rate of $a_2$. She reaches the ground with a speed of $v_2$. Find her average speed for the fall. (The answer should be $18.5\ \text{m/s}$.)

Note: In the diagram, replace "x" with "y". :)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OPTZfWI.png]

$
\text{Let upwards be the positive y direction.}\\
\text{Givens:}\\
y_1 = -59.7\ \text{m}\\
v_0 = 0\ \text{m/s}\\
v_2 = -3.41\ \text{m/s}\\
a_1 = -9.8\ \text{m/s$^2$}\\
a_2 = 1.60\ \text{m/s$^2$}\\
\text{Solve for $t_1$:}\\
y_1 - y_0 = \frac{1}{2}a_1t^2+v_0t\qquad\text{for}\ \ y_1 = 0; v_0 = 0; t=t_1.\\
t_1 = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2y_1}{a_1}}\\
t_1 \approx \pm 3.4905\ \text{s}.\\
\text{Plug $t_1$ into the velocity equation for $v_1$ to find $v_1$:}\\
v_1 = a_1t_1 + v_0\\
v_1 \approx -34.207.\\
\text{Plug $v_1$ into the velocity equation for $v_2$ to find $t_2$:}\\
v_2 = a_2t_2 + v_1\\
t_2 = \frac{v_2 - v_1}{a_2}\\
t_2 \approx 19.248\ \text{s}.\\
\text{Plug $t_2$ into the position equation for $y_2$ to find $y_2$.}\\
y_2 = \frac{1}{2}a_2t_2^2+v_1t_2 + x_1\\
y_2 \approx -422\ \text{m}.\\
\text{Now solve for $\lvert\overline{v}\rvert$:}\\
\lvert\overline{v}\rvert = \lvert\frac{x_2 - x_0}{t_2 - t_0}\rvert\\
\lvert\overline{v}\rvert \approx 21.9\ \text{m/s} \neq 18.5\ \text{m/s}.
$

My solution is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points:

1. The value you calculated for $t_2$ is the time taken for the person to fall the distance $y_2-y_1$
2. Thus, the total time to fall the total distance of $422m$:
   $$T= t_1 + t_2$$
   $$=3.4905 + 19.248 $$
3. average speed is just total distance divided by total time
4. $v_{avg}=\frac{422}{3.4905 + 19.248}= 18.56ms^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish I had realized that detail! :)